# Hot key to select 'Look in' find option in Visual Studio 2010 (or more generally, can one build shortcuts that pass parameters?)

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I find myself spending an extra 2 seconds about 100 times a day switching between 'Current Document' and 'Current Project' (or 'Current Solution') in the VS2010 'Find and Replace' box.  'Look in' always contains whatever was selected last.

Is there an existing shortcut for this or a way to build a shortcut that will allow you pre-select options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a macro to do this, and then maybe assign the macro to a key combo.

To test this, go to:
-Tools > Macro > Record Temporary Macro.

-Then do your find, selecting the desired 'Look In' option.

-Hit stop to end the recording.

You can save the temporary macro, and view it in the Macro Explorer.  (Right Click > Edit to see the code).

It should look something like:

```
  DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.Find")
  DTE.Find.Target = vsFindTarget.vsFindTargetCurrentProject
```

You can change the last line to set the target to wherever you want it to look.

Repeat for each of your desired 'Look In' targets.

Comment: Coda:  Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard to assign hotkeys.

Comment: @jordanpg, that won't work in this case, because "look in" is not one of the selectable commands that you can assign a hotkey to (unless it has an unintuitive name and I've missed it).